# Elasticsearch indexing with elisions

Tags: elasticsearch

How would I index words, such as *L'Oréal* in Elasticsearch?

User might type in couple of ways:

1. Loreal
2. L'Oreal
3. L'Oréal

Ideally, I'd like all of them to output loreal. I wouldn't like to do this manually for each *exceptional keyword*.

[Elision Token Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/analysis-elision-tokenfilter.html) seems to be useful, but it would work only for 2nd and 3rd cases.

Any ideas how I'd make all of these keywords to output same token `loreal`?

Comment: What language is your search in? If this is english and a special case just for L'Oreal, I'd just use a synonym filter to map all of these variations to the same term.

Comment: It was English. I could've created a synonym, but who knows how many of other cases like that were there. :)

Comment: That's true. English is pretty bad about borrowing. I'd just be worried that the character filter solution might mess up english contractions and possessives, which may be more common that the exceptions. Search is such a delicate dance in that way. In the end it depends on the data. We, for example, have no possessives or contractions at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elision token filter will actually remove the specified articles, so you'll never have `loreal` in your token, i.e. the first `l` will never make it.

What I suggest is the following using a combination of `asciifolding` and `lowercase`:

```
PUT test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "my_analyzer": {
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "filter": [
                  "standard",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "lowercase"
               ],
               "char_filter": [
                  "apostrophe"
               ]
            }
         },
         "char_filter": {
            "apostrophe": {
               "type": "mapping",
               "mappings": [
                  "'=>"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

With `my_analyzer`, all the input strings you've specified will be transformed into the `loreal` token.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test_index/_analyze?analyzer=my_analyzer&pretty' -d "Loreal"
=> loreal

curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test_index/_analyze?analyzer=my_analyzer&pretty' -d "L'Oreal"
=> loreal

curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test_index/_analyze?analyzer=my_analyzer&pretty' -d "L'Oréal"
=> loreal
```

Comment: I thought about this as well. Thought there might be a better solution. Thank you!

Comment: It's definitely not the only solution, but one of the simplest, in my opinion.